# Errors in the OLAP storage engine: A duplicate attribute key has been found when processing

Tags: sql-server, ssas

When I try to process my cube and specifically the Employee_DIM, I get the following error :

> Errors in the OLAP storage engine: A duplicate attribute key has been
>   found when processing: Table: 'dbo_Employee_DIM', Column: 'Firstname',
>   Value: 'Aurélie'. The attribute is 'Firstname'.

I think that duplicate values for the column Firstname are considered as keys. After checking with the Employee_DIM :

```
 SELECT [Firstname], COUNT([Firstname]) AS dup_count
     FROM [Database].[dbo].[Employee]
        GROUP BY [Firstname]
             HAVING (COUNT([Firstname]) > 1)
                ORDER BY [Firstname]
```

[image]

Is there any alternative to leave only the business key in Employee_DIM and get Lastname and Firstname without adding them in the dimension for a future use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find the solution here : [Errors in the OLAP storage engine: A duplicate attribute key has been found when processing](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f9b61650-7ba3-4a5a-8882-9f82b98cc20a/errors-in-the-olap-storage-engine-a-duplicate-attribute-key-has-been-found-when-processing?forum=sqlanalysisservices)